Blazor with .NET 8 - Page that was not working has started working for uncertain reason
I have a simple page in my .NET 8 Blazor Client project (see code below).
The code was always giving me "FirstName is required" and "LastName is required" messages. I didn't understand why - it was structured similar to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0
I decided to see if it would work server side, to see if that was a constraint. I pasted the code file into the Server project in my solution then added rendermode InteractiveServer.
It worked.
I then moved this file back to the Client project, changed render mode to InteractiveAuto, did a Clean and Rebuild all, which I expected (hoped!) would clean any cached WebAssembly. To my surprise it now worked on the client.
There was absolutely no fancy code communicating with the server. What you see is "what is". Why has it started working?
Now, I don't want to accept this code as working, for all I know the interactive server version that first worked could be cached somehow.
Can anyone tell me if this is valid .NET 8 Blazor client code and, if not, what I need to add or change to it?
In addition, is there a way to check that the WebAssembly loaded is completely fresh (ie: not cached by Edge browser)
Thanks.
@page "/formdataentryclient"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<h3>Data Entry Form using EditForm and built in Input components</h3>

<EditForm Model="@person" FormName="DataEntryForm" Enhance OnInvalidSubmit="OnInvalidSubmit" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    
    <div>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="person!.FirstName"></InputText><ValidationMessage For="@(() => person!.FirstName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="person!.LastName"></InputText><ValidationMessage For="@(() => person!.LastName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    public class Person
    {
        [Required] [StringLength(10)] 
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
        
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "DataEntryForm")]
    private Person? person { get; set; } 

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        person = new();
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Submitted: {person!.FirstName} {person!.LastName}");
    }

    private void OnInvalidSubmit(EditContext obj)
    {
        foreach (var message in obj.GetValidationMessages())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }

}


Where did you select Interctivity?  Global or Per Page/Component.  What was the initial Rendermode set on the form.  My guess is your original form was statically rendered.

Some advice [that you're welcome to ignore]. Building an InteractiveAuto application [especially if you've chosen Per Page/Component interactivity] is jumping in at the extremely deep end [like The Challenger Deep]. Chose either Server or WebAssembly. You'll travel a lot few wrong roads.

I think the original rendermode was set to InteractiveAuto.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis best I learn the hard way so I know what not to do next time :-) .  This is an extremely simple page yet wouldn't work on the client .. until I got it working on the server project. If my code looks OK to you then I can treat it as a glitch, some caching issue in Edge or my VS 2022 Community setup.

There's nothing wrong with your code, I suspect it was statically rendering.  Here's a commentary of mine from the early days of Net8 explaining some of the challenges with InteractiveAuto.   Good coding.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering

Your .NET 8 Blazor client code is valid, and the issue likely stemmed from caching or state problems that were resolved when moving the file between projects and performing a Clean/Rebuild. Blazor WebAssembly apps can experience issues due to cached files, which may have caused the validation messages to persist incorrectly. To ensure a fresh WebAssembly load, you can clear your browser cache, disable cache in Developer Tools, use query strings to bust cache, or manage cache with a service worker. Your implementation of the EditForm and validation logic is correct.
